# How do i display only the specific console when my condition inside loop is met

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

THIS IS MY CONTROLLER FUNCTION:

```
$scope.Save = function () {

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.listOfnames.length; i++){
         if($scope.listOfnames[i].surname == $scope.name.surname){
            console.log("This surname is already exist!");

        }else{
            console.log("save this surname.");
            }
    }
}
```

THIS MY OUTPUT IN CONSOLE :

```
save this surname.

This surname is already exist!

save this surname.
```

FOR EXAMPLE, I HAVE ALREADY A "STUART" SURNAME IN MY $scope.listOfnames,
AND WHEN I INPUT "STUART" SURNAME ALSO IN MY SURNAME INPUT FIELD,
IT MUST DISPLAY "This surname is already exist!" ONLY IN MY CONSOLE.

I KNOW THAT I HAVE A PROBLEM ON MY FOR LOOP, WHAT SHOULD I DO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that on console because "STUART" is the second value on your array. You can do something like:

```
$scope.Save = function () {
    var found  = false;

    //Loop thru the array and check each. If found change the value of var found
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.listOfnames.length; i++){
        if( $scope.listOfnames[i].surname == $scope.name.surname ){
              found = true;
        }
    }


    if ( found ) {
        console.log("This surname is already exist!");
    } else {
        console.log("save this surname.");
    }
}
```